# Wrong expectation when count and join 3 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: broadcasts, broadcasts_likes and broadcasts_viewers:

[image]

I want return result include total_likes, total_viewers but when I run this sql, the expectation is wrong, could you help me check this. I just want use sql normally, don't use sub query. Here is my sql:

```
SELECT `b`.*, 
COUNT(`bl`.`broadcast_id`) AS `total_likes`,      
COUNT(`bv`.`broadcast_id`) AS `total_viewers` 
FROM `broadcasts` `b` 
LEFT JOIN `broadcasts_likes` `bl` 
ON `b`.`broadcast_id` = `bl`.`broadcast_id` 
LEFT JOIN `broadcasts_viewers` `bv` 
ON `b`.`broadcast_id` = `bv`.`broadcast_id` 
GROUP BY `b`.`broadcast_id`;
```

Comment: Consider formating your post in future.

Comment: Pls share the expected output and the output you get from running the above query!

Comment: Why no `subqueries`?  The problem is you're duplicating results with the `join`.  You most likely will need to use 2 subqueries -- do the `sum` there.

Comment: broadcast_id   total_likes   total_viewers
7                           9                   9
8                            4                  4
9                            0                   0
10                          1                  1
Expect is:
broadcast_id   total_likes   total_viewers
7                           3                   3
8                            2                  2
9                            0                   0
10                          1                  1

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you. Btw, I don't one use subqueries because I will create view from these tables, and view don't permit me with sql have subqueries

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to switch to `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT `b`.*, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT `bl`.profile_id`) AS `total_likes`,      
       COUNT(DISTINCT `bv`.view_profile_id) AS `total_viewers` 
FROM `broadcasts` `b` LEFT JOIN
     `broadcasts_likes` `bl` 
     ON `b`.`broadcast_id` = `bl`.`broadcast_id` LEFT JOIN
     `broadcasts_viewers` `bv` 
     ON `b`.`broadcast_id` = `bv`.`broadcast_id` 
GROUP BY `b`.`broadcast_id`;
```

If broadcast have lots of views and lots of likes, this won't scale particularly well.  In that case, you can aggregate the tables before joining or use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT `b`.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM broadcasts_likes bl
        WHERE `b`.`broadcast_id` = `bl`.`broadcast_id`
       ) as `total_likes`,      
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM broadcasts_viewers bv
        WHERE `b`.`broadcast_id` = `bv`.`broadcast_id`
       ) as `total_viewers` 
FROM `broadcasts` `b`;
```

Actually, with indexes on `broadcasts_likes(broadcast_id)` and `broadcasts_viewers(broadcast_id)`, this very should have very good performance.

Comment: Thank you, it's okey with distinct keyword